# g++ can't find include files even with -I

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, g++

I'm trying to compile an example from a C++ library on Github.

Here is the command I used to compile the code:

```bash
$ g++ -g main.cpp -o main -I~/NMEA2000_socketCAN -I~/NMEA0183 -I~/NMEA2000/src -lnmea2000
main.cpp:25:10: fatal error: NMEA2000_CAN.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include "NMEA2000_CAN.h"  
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here is where `NMEA2000_CAN.h` located:

```bash
$ ls ~/NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000_CAN.h
/home/{...}/NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000_CAN.h
```

I've also tried using <NMEA2000_CAN.h>

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my platform:

```
(compiling on RPI)
Linux boatpi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is the search directories output? To be more specific, if you add `--verbose` in your compile command, what did it output?

Comment: Try providing an absolute path to the include directory. `~` does not get expanded by your shell when it's in the middle of a different string. Compare `echo ~/foo` to `echo -I~/foo`.

Comment: Thanks! It was the relative path (~) that was getting me.